# Bootstrap table with no padding/margin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed col-md-12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
    </tr>
  </thead
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I use Bootstrap as my framework and it looks like this:

[image]

How can i stretch the input width & height to fit table cell?

I'm using CSS on input: `width: 100%`
I've tried CSS on td: `padding: 0; margin: 0;`

Comment: give tr padding 0 aswell and make them important both td and tr

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Araz comment:

```
tr td{
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `padding:0` to `td`. Place your style sheet below `bootstrap.css`. so `!important` is not required. if you use css in inline then `!important` is required. `.form-control` class is used to make input width `100%` of the cell.

```css
td{padding:0px !important}
.form-control{border-radius:0px !important;}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed col-md-12">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
    </tr>
  </thead
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but `form-control` still leaves some margin/padding. Also the corners of input get rounded.. but a Bootstrap table has flatten edges!

Comment: did you added the `css` i given in your `html` or `stylesheet`

Answer (score -2):

To remove table gaps and margin, add this to your css file

```css
table { 
   border-spacing: 0px;
}
```