# Table in bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

from where the extra 'green' portion came from?

[This is my nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4GYN.png)
[The green portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBGYo.png)

How can i get rid of this?

**Note:** When I put normal text here, I get it nicely formatted vertically center, but when using table it doesn't.

Here is my html structures.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <table class="table table-sm table-condensed table-borderless">
        <tbody class="user-logout">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-light">Farhad Hossain</td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+current_user.trainer.picture) }}"
                         width="56" height="56" class="rounded-circle" alt="">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="text-decoration-none text-warning" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
```

Any hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the default styling for bootstrap tables contains plenty of margin underneath, that is visible here. You could try to override that by setting `margin-bottom: 0 !important` ([there is a similar question out here addressing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40258014/bootstrap-table-with-no-padding-margin)), but generally, as a learning curve thing, I don't think you should be using a table for these purposes. A table is for showing data, as an actual table, not for aligning things, but well, we all have learnt HTML and CSS first by using tables and this works too, unless you need to shift the order of these things or make it responsive.

Comment: Thank you so much @roye7777777 , That works for me!
Is there any better solution to do the job without table?

Comment: I would recommend you to try some things with the `float` property, though use that with a so-called clearfix (you can search for it, it has to do with using `clear:both;` in conjunction with `float`, though float is a bit outdated. A more advanced and modern way of aligning things is by using flexbox. Read about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).